# Update FSCalendar Header value with select date swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, fscalendar

I have set FSCalendar scope mode as week. After that  Header date format I have set `calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy EEEE"` 
and it's showing correct format.

- Problem I am facing it gives start of week date. How can I update value of Header if I select any date.
  I haven't found any property or method for it.
- My selection date is 13-Sep-2021 but Header date is 16-Sep-2021.

Code and Image added.

```
func setupFSCalendar() {

        ViewCalendar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 78, width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
        ViewCalendar.backgroundColor = ("#455a64").toColor()
        let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ViewCalendar.frame.width, height: 250))
        calendar.layoutIfNeeded()
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .white  // week name color
        calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy EEEE"
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleColor = UIColor.white
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        calendar.appearance.titleWeekendColor = UIColor.white
        
        calendar.appearance.titleDefaultColor =  .white
        calendar.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        calendar.appearance.weekdayFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        calendar.appearance.titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        calendar.appearance.titleTodayColor = ("#54a767").toColor()
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor  = ("#788f9b").toColor()
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = nil
        
        calendar.appearance.subtitleWeekendColor = UIColor.white
        calendar.placeholderType = .none   /// to remove last month dates
        calendar.appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0   // removes next prev month title.
        calendar.backgroundColor = .clear 
        
        calendar.firstWeekday = 2
        calendar.scope = .week
        
        ViewCalendar.addSubview(calendar)
    }


    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        print(date)
        calendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
        calendar.select(date)
        
    }
```

[image: FSCalendar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the text of visible `FSCalendarHeaderCell`s from the selected date as below

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    print(date)
    calendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
    calendar.select(date)
    
    //format the selectedDate and set to the header
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat
    
    for cell in calendar.calendarHeaderView.collectionView.visibleCells {
        (cell as! FSCalendarHeaderCell).titleLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help, could you please accept the answer since it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: bothering you again, but I have observed whenever we load application it by default header date set to `16 September 2021 Thursday` as today its `15 September 2021`

Comment: If you want the headerView to have today in the beginning, Use a new Date()  and run the headerView title change logic at the end of setupFSCalendar().

Comment: yes I am using new `Date()` but there is not `HeaderView Title property`

Comment: You need to run below code(already there in the above answer) for headerView title changes with a new date at end of setupFSCalendar()     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat
    
    for cell in calendar.calendarHeaderView.collectionView.visibleCells {
        (cell as! FSCalendarHeaderCell).titleLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

Comment: Yes I have used the same code but its not working, its not coming in For loop,
your code works in `didSelect` but If I use to set it `onLoad` after `setupFSCalendar()` its not changing Header today date.

Comment: I see, try using the code in viewDidAppear() method. Should work

Comment: unfortunately not. Even I haven't found any property for it.

Comment: I found one weird way hide header and `calendar.headerHeight=0` and put the customized header on top.

Comment: I could have a look, If you can post another question with the latest setupFSCalender() and where you are calling this method in your controller.

Comment: sure I will post and share with you.